# How to display separate headers for different rows in pageblock table?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Below is the visualforce page i have created 
 i want to display a text on the starting of the row like "Resdential for Sale" which has no header

[image: i want to display a text on the starting of the row like "Resdential for Sale"] 
below is the Visualforce Page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Development_Project__c">
<apex:form >


            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Development_Project__c}" var="dp" columnsWidth="10%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%">
                   <apex:column>
                         <apex:facet name="header">
                       </apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>

                   <apex:column  headerValue="#Units">
                       <apex:inputfield value="{!Development_Project__c.Residential_for_Sale_Total_Unit_Size__c}"/>
                   </apex:column>
                   <apex:column  headervalue="GSF">
                       <apex:inputField value="{!Development_Project__c.Residential_for_Sale_Total_Gross_sf__c}"/>
                   </apex:column>
                   <apex:column  headervalue="NSF">
                       <apex:inputField value="{!Development_Project__c.Residential_for_Sale_Total_Net_sf__c}"/>
                   </apex:column>
                   <apex:column  headervalue="EFF%" />
                   <apex:column  headervalue="AVG Unit" />
                   <apex:column  headervalue="F to F Height" />


            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

i want to create a pageblock table in below format
[image]

how to create the "Resdential for sale","Resdential for Rent","Hotel","Retail","Office" and "Parking" which are only Labels.

Comment: remove unwanted code which is not relevant to your question

Comment: @user45226, I am having a similar Requirement. I know this must have resolved, could you please provide me some links or piece of code how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code:

```
                <apex:column>
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                   </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
```

You are defining a column without any header or value, so it ends up as a blank row as you see in your attached image. If you want to display something in there, just add an attribute to your  tag as in the other columns below, either a header via *headerValue="Residential for Sale"* or *value="Residential for Sale"*. Example:

```
                <apex:column value="Residential for Sale">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                   </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
```

If you want some dynamic content, you will need to work with a data structure in your extension and populate it with the desired text.